# ¿Cual es el motivo del error si la etiqueta se cierra y abre correctamente en xml?

Tags: xml

este es mi segundo código en XML introducir el código aquí(autodidacta) y me da un error de "mismatched tag" en el cierre de premio cuando está abierto correctamente (o eso creo yo) No sé si alguien puede echarme una mano. Por otra parte me da un error en "resumen" de no character data is allowed by content model. Muchisimas gracias por dedicarle algo de tiempo a esto.                                                                                                                                                            .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE premios_hugo [ 
<!ELEMENT premios_hugo (premio*)>
<!ELEMENT premio (edicion*)>
<!ELEMENT edicion (año, libro, autor)>
<!ATTLIST edicion numero CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT año (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT libro (resumen,genero,subgenero,idioma,titulo_original,editorial,pais)>
        <!ELEMENT resumen (#PCDATA)>
         <!ELEMENT genero (#PCDATA)>
         <!ELEMENT subgenero (#PCDATA)>
         <!ELEMENT titulo_original (#PCDATA)>
         <!ELEMENT idioma (#PCDATA)>
          <!ELEMENT editorial (#PCDATA)>
           <!ELEMENT pais (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT autor (biografia,nacionalidad,nacimiento,fallecimiento,educacion)>
        <!ELEMENT biografia (#PCDATA)>
                 <!ELEMENT nacionalidad (#PCDATA)>
                 <!ELEMENT nacimiento (#PCDATA)>
                  <!ELEMENT fallecimiento (#PCDATA)>
                    <!ELEMENT educacion (#PCDATA)>

   ]>                

<premios_hugo>

<premio>

<edicion numero="1">
<año>1953</año>
<libro>El hombre demolido
<resumen>El libro está ambientado en el siglo XXIV. 
Los viajes espaciales se han convertido en algo corriente y existen colonias 
humanas en Marte, Venus y los satélites principales de los planetas exteriores.</resumen>
<genero>Novela</genero>
<subgenero>Ciencia ficción especulativa</subgenero>
<idioma>Inglés</idioma>
<titulo_original>The Demolished Man</titulo_original>
<editorial>Shasta Publishers</editorial>
<pais>Estados Unidos</pais>
</libro>

<autor>Alfred Baster
<biografia>publicó su primer relato en 1939, 
su salto a la fama vino a comienzos de los cincuenta. Asentada posteriormente con
Las estrellas, mi destino, su segunda novela</biografia>
<nacionalidad>Estadounidense</nacionalidad>
<nacimiento>18-12-1913</nacimiento>
<fallecimiento>30-09-1982</fallecimiento>
<educacion>Universidad de Pensilvania</educacion>
</autor>

<edicion numero="2">
<año>1955</año>
<libro>La máquina de la eternidad
<resumen>esta obra trata de la inteligencia artificial y sus implicaciones,
 antes de que la ciencia oficial creara dicho concepto.
</resumen>
<genero>Novela</genero>
<subgenero>Ciencia ficción especulativa</subgenero>
<idioma>Inglés</idioma>
<titulo_original>The Forever Machine</titulo_original>
<editorial>Gnome Press</editorial>
<pais>Estados Unidos</pais>
</libro>

<autor>Frank Riley
<biografia>Editor de Los Angeles Magazine, guionista y publicista, famoso por su programa de radio 
El padre Anton Dymek</biografia>
<nacionalidad>Estadounidense</nacionalidad>
<nacimiento>30-09-1918</nacimiento>
<fallecimiento>8-12-1996</fallecimiento>
<educacion>Universidad de Los Angeles</educacion>
</autor>
</edicion>


<edicion numero="3">
<año>1956</año>
<libro>Estrella doble
<resumen>La historia transcurre alrededor de un actor brillante del futuro, Lawrence Smythe 
quien considera que podría haberse convertido en un segundo Charlie Chaplin
 si no fuera por su egocentrismo y su carácter aislado. Al borde de la miseria al comienzo de la historia es contratado por
  un piloto espacial para representar a una importante figura pública.
</resumen>
<genero>Novela</genero>
<subgenero>Ciencia ficción</subgenero>
<idioma>Inglés</idioma>
<titulo_original>Double Star</titulo_original>
<editorial>Doubleday</editorial>
<pais>Estados Unidos</pais>
</libro>

<autor>Robert A.Heinlein
<biografia>Militar de profesión se reconvierte en escritor de ciencia ficción a la edad de 29 años</biografia>
<nacionalidad>Estadounidense</nacionalidad>
<nacimiento>7-07-1907</nacimiento>
<fallecimiento>8-05-1988</fallecimiento>
<educacion>Academia Naval de los Estados Unidos</educacion>
</autor>

</edicion>
</premio>

</premios_hugo>
```

Comment: Te aconsejo usar `xml formatters`online para que te formateen el xml bien tabulado y así puedas ver mejor el error, de hecho, cuando lo he intentado formatear en https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html me dice que hay alguna etiqueta edicion que no se ha cerrado en la línea 103.

Comment: Muchas gracias, esa web es una maravilla.

Answer (score 2):

Te falta cerrar el primer elemento `<edicion>`

Comment: Cierto, madre, esto es un sinfín de errores :/

Mil gracias por echarle un ojo

Answer (score 1):

Acabo de ver el error, como te he dicho en el comentario, te aconsejo usar formateadores de `xml`. El problema se encuentra en la primera edición que no la tienes cerrada, con todo solucionado tu xml quedaría así:(si quieres usa un comparador de archivos para ver dónde está la diferencia)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE premios_hugo [ 
<!ELEMENT premios_hugo (premio*)>
<!ELEMENT premio (edicion*)>
<!ELEMENT edicion (año, libro, autor)>
<!ATTLIST edicion numero CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT año (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT libro (resumen,genero,subgenero,idioma,titulo_original,editorial,pais)>
<!ELEMENT resumen (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT genero (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT subgenero (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT titulo_original (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT idioma (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT editorial (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT pais (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT autor (biografia,nacionalidad,nacimiento,fallecimiento,educacion)>
<!ELEMENT biografia (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT nacionalidad (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT nacimiento (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT fallecimiento (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT educacion (#PCDATA)>

]>                

<premios_hugo>

<premio>

    <edicion numero="1">
        <año>1953</año>
        <libro>El hombre demolido
            <resumen>El libro está ambientado en el siglo XXIV. 
Los viajes espaciales se han convertido en algo corriente y existen colonias 
humanas en Marte, Venus y los satélites principales de los planetas exteriores. 
</resumen>
            <genero>Novela</genero>
            <subgenero>Ciencia ficción especulativa</subgenero>
            <idioma>Inglés</idioma>
            <titulo_original>The Demolished Man</titulo_original>
            <editorial>Shasta Publishers</editorial>
            <pais>Estados Unidos</pais>
        </libro>
        <autor>Alfred Baster
            <biografia>publicó su primer relato en 1939, 
su salto a la fama vino a comienzos de los cincuenta. Asentada posteriormente con
Las estrellas, mi destino, su segunda novela</biografia>
            <nacionalidad>Estadounidense</nacionalidad>
            <nacimiento>18-12-1913</nacimiento>
            <fallecimiento>30-09-1982</fallecimiento>
            <educacion>Universidad de Pensilvania</educacion>
        </autor>
    </edicion>
    <edicion numero="2">
        <año>1955</año>
        <libro>La máquina de la eternidad
            <resumen>esta obra trata de la inteligencia artificial y sus 
implicaciones,
antes de que la ciencia oficial creara dicho concepto.
            </resumen>
            <genero>Novela</genero>
            <subgenero>Ciencia ficción especulativa</subgenero>
            <idioma>Inglés</idioma>
            <titulo_original>The Forever Machine</titulo_original>
            <editorial>Gnome Press</editorial>
            <pais>Estados Unidos</pais>
        </libro>

        <autor>Frank Riley
            <biografia>Editor de Los Angeles Magazine, guionista y publicista, famoso 
por su programa de radio 
El padre Anton Dymek</biografia>
            <nacionalidad>Estadounidense</nacionalidad>
            <nacimiento>30-09-1918</nacimiento>
            <fallecimiento>8-12-1996</fallecimiento>
            <educacion>Universidad de Los Angeles</educacion>
        </autor>
    </edicion>


    <edicion numero="3">
        <año>1956</año>
        <libro>Estrella doble
            <resumen>La historia transcurre alrededor de un actor brillante del 
futuro, Lawrence Smythe 
quien considera que podría haberse convertido en un segundo Charlie Chaplin
si no fuera por su egocentrismo y su carácter aislado. Al borde de la miseria al 
comienzo de la historia es contratado por
un piloto espacial para representar a una importante figura pública.
            </resumen>
            <genero>Novela</genero>
            <subgenero>Ciencia ficción</subgenero>
            <idioma>Inglés</idioma>
            <titulo_original>Double Star</titulo_original>
            <editorial>Doubleday</editorial>
            <pais>Estados Unidos</pais>
        </libro>

        <autor>Robert A.Heinlein
            <biografia>Militar de profesión se reconvierte en escritor de ciencia 
ficción a la edad de 29 años</biografia>
            <nacionalidad>Estadounidense</nacionalidad>
            <nacimiento>7-07-1907</nacimiento>
            <fallecimiento>8-05-1988</fallecimiento>
            <educacion>Academia Naval de los Estados Unidos</educacion>
        </autor>

    </edicion>
</premio>

</premios_hugo>
```

Comment: Mil gracias, he usado la web y también he copiado el código que me has puesto, me sigue dando un error en la línea 32 "no character data is allowed by content". hasta donde alcanzo entiendo que está correcto. ¿Puede ser el XML Copy editor?

Comment: Si te ha fallado en la línea 32, mira el encoding, ya que te está fallando por la tilde en la a de "<resumen>El libro está ambientado en el siglo XXIV. 
Los viajes espaciales se han convertido en algo corriente y existen colonias 
humanas en Marte, Venus y los satélites principales de los planetas exteriores. 
</resumen>", asegurate que el encodiing sigue siendo UTF-8. Si no es ese el problema es que igual no has copiado bien el xml que te pongo en la respuesta, porque yo lo estoy usando para probar y no me da ningún error :/

Comment: Pues creo que iba a ser, eso. Mil gracias!!!!!